# Magento Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dme_dubai.log_visitor' doesn't exist

Tags: magento

Getting Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1286040099769 
Tried to restore backup still the error is not resolved.
when i see report the following links i recieved:

```html
a:5:{i:0;s:233:"
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dme_dubai.log_visitor' doesn't exist, query was: 
INSERT INTO `log_visitor` (`session_id`, `first_visit_at`, `last_visit_at`, `last_url_id`, `store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
";i:1;s:2752:"
#0 /home/dme/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/dme/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/dme/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 /home/dme/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /home/dme/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#6 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor', Array)
#7 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/dme/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#12 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#14 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#16 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /home/dme/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /home/dme/public_html/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"english";}
```

Comment: Somebody dropped a table, table `log_visitor` needs to be recreated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Check if other log tables exists in your MySQL database. Mage_Log module has following tables;

- log_customer
- log_visitor
- log_visitor_info
- log_url
- log_url_info
- log_summary
- log_summary_type
- log_quote
- log_visitor_online

**If it's just log_visitor table that doesn't exists** in your database, you can create it by running following SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `dme_dubai`.`log_visitor` (
    `visitor_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Visitor ID',
    `session_id` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Session ID',
    `first_visit_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'First Visit Time',
    `last_visit_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Last Visit Time',
    `last_url_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Last URL ID',
    `store_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
    PRIMARY KEY (`visitor_id`)
);
```

However **if every log table is missing** you need to run Mage_Log setup, by deleting the row in core_resource table which has log_setup value for code column.